# UITextfiled is storing Text value in Memory heap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, heap-memory, memory-dump

I am facing a problem with UITextField. While entering text into a textfield, it's storing the text into memory heap. The textfield is released and the pointer is set to nil after use. I also tried to set the value to an empty string. When I checked the heap the old value was still present there. 
If I again enter a value into text field before release it's also storing it in the memory heap. After the second input, there are two old text(NSString) values in the memory heap. 
 
I am facing this issue in a login password field and the password gets leaked in vulnerability testing.

Comment: post your code... help us to help you

Comment: are you not using arc? why are you releasing objects?